# Excel Data Validation: If any cell in this row isn't blank there must be a value in this cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation, microsoft-excel-365

I'm trying to set up data validation in a cell so that if **any** cell in a range in that row has a non-blank cell, the cell with the validation must have a value from its drop-down list. As data is entered with copy/paste, I use "Circle Invalid Data" to find errors, and it's flagging *every* cell with that validation even if the entire row is blank. What am I doing wrong?

The formula I'm using is `=IF(COUNTBLANK($A2:$AF2)<32,States,Blank)`. Ignore blanks is unchecked. The table "States" has a list of state codes, and the table "Blank" has one blank cell. I have verified that the range and number of cells is correct. I used delete to be sure all the cells were blank.

Comment: Is your table of states also defined as a named range? As referring to a table generally requires to have a table and column name.

Comment: @gns100 Just the table name can be used without qualification as a function argument, but the function will apply to all the cells in the table.  If “States” is a single column, it should work fine.

Comment: The states are a single column named range. Used by itself in a validation it works perfectly, so I'm confident the issue is in the formula.